# How to make all div fit into the screen without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have around 10 images aligining side by side each of size 150x150.Each image kept inside a their rspective div.The images doesnt fit the screen.I dont want them to fit to screen.After 6 images remainig 4 images come below the other 6 images.I want all of them to align horizontally and fit to scrren.Width and height of div is given same as size of image

```
<style>

.wrapper{

     margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;

.zero
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.one
    {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;
.two
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.three
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.four
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.five
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.six
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.seven
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.eight
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;

.nine
    {
    margin-left:259px;
    margin-top:948px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    display-inline:block;


</style>




<body>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="zero">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>

  <div class="one">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>

    <div class="two">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
<div class="three">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
<div class="four">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
<div class="five">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
<div class="six">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
<div class="seven">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
<div class="eight">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

 </div>
<div class="nine">
    <img src="images/image.png"/>

    </div>
</div>
</body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: You need all 10 images horizontal side by side?

Comment: i suspect you need to review your layout choices. `inline-block` and `float` don't work together and such large margins aren't really optimal. [**LearnLaout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Also, what is supposed to happen if the screen is less than 1500px wide?

Comment: Yes I need all images side by side,tha images can shrink their sizes.Okay if such large margins arent optimal how would I position the images.I really need that much margin between each images.What can be the solution?Yes,that is what Im confused,what should I do if the screen size is less?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **flexbox** to solve your problem `.container {display:flex;}` the children of the container will grow according to the available size [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bddxVE).

here you see adding more images will not create scrollbars.
the default property `flex-wrap` is `nowrap` which creates the layout you want.

Keep in mind the property does not work on older IE browsers.

Answer (score -1):

I had a auto-opening, auto-closing popup that was a revolution slider with triple borders wherein I had to figure out how to get the right and bottom borders to be visible within the scrollbars. (Initially the scrollbars were on top of the bottom and right triple borders).

Here's my code:

```
.slotholder {
border: 2px solid #000000;
height: calc(100% - 17px) !important; /*minus height of bottom scrollbar*/
width: calc(100% - 17px) !important; /*minus width of bottom scrollbar*/
}
.slotholder:before {
content:"";
position: absolute;
top:5px;
bottom:5px;
left:5px;
right:5px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.slotholder:after {
content:"";
position: absolute;
top:15px;
bottom:15px;
left:15px;
right:15px;
border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer, but be aware that posts including an **unsolicited commercial advertisement** can get deleted as spam.  For more see [What is the exact definition of “spam” for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638).  I've edited that portion out for now.